# RequiredFieldValidator not Validating

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a control on an ASP.NET page with a required field validator. Only problem is that when I go to change pages via my page buttons it doesn't cause validation. Here is the code, can anyone see what's wrong?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblD_Year" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
                       Text="Fiscal Year" CssClass="h2"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlD_Year" runat="server" Width="100px" TabIndex="8" 
                    AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="box" CausesValidation="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">Select Year</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>                               

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvD_Year" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="ddlD_Year" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" 
                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select Year" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: The button does not have CausesValidation="false", correct?  The button is also in the same validation group?

Comment: It does have the causesvalidation ="false" because when people start to enter information on the form if they press the wrong button and need to move to a different page it wasn't allowing the move because validation would occur. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set initial value as `InitialValue="-1"` for validator or any value which you consider to be empty, if selected

Comment: That is the whole code. It's a very simple form, select a value and press a button.

Comment: ok add ValidationGroup="something" to the control(dropdown), validator and submit button

Answer (score 0):

**Set InitialValue="0"**

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvD_Year" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="ddlD_Year" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" 
                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="0" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: That didn't work. I originally thought that was the problem as well to no avail.

Comment: @developthestars Make sure you set the CausesValidation of the button (on which click you want validation to fire) to true. You can set CausesValidation to false for all the other buttons (on which you do not want the validation to fire)